# HTTP header "Content-type: multipart/mixed" causes "400 Bad request"

Tags: php, http, http-headers, fsockopen

I'm trying to upload  a file to a remote server using php's fsockopen. If my request looks like:

```
$httpContent = [
        "POST /index.php HTTP/1.1", 
        "Host: The IP address of my remote server", 
        "Connection: Close", 
        "User-Agent: My client"
];
```

the server responses with `200 OK`. However if I add

```
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=".md5('myBoundary'), 
"--".md5('myBoundary'), 
"Content-Type: text/plain", 
"value", 
"--".md5('myBoundary')."--"
```

The server returns "400 Bad Request". Everything seems fine to me, but somehow it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit (@Rei advised to post a dump of the request):**

this is what echoes in client's terminal

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: The IP address of my remote server
Connection: Close
User-Agent: My client
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
Content-Type: text/plain
value
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49--
```

And this is what the server gets (caught with tcpdump):

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: The IP address of my remote server
Connection: Close
User-Agent: My client
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
Content-Type: text/plain
value
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49--
```

I personally don't see any difference between the two and also don't see anything wrong with the request. Yet, the server returns "400 Bad Request".

*Note: The "The IP address of my remote server" is a real IP address, but I'm not posting it due to security concerns.

**Note: Didn't mention that the PHP script is run in a CLI environment and is not used as a web-application back-end (the requests are NOT prepared by a web browser).

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a problem with the request, so you need to show your actual HTTP request. The problem should be obvious then.

Comment: How to get the whole request?

Comment: Combine everything you're `fwrite()`-ing into a variable and `echo` it in the end. Alternatively, every time you call `fwrite()`, pass the same string to `echo`. Make sure that you `echo` nothing else or you'll confuse yourself.

Comment: Question edited with the details provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as I suspected, the HTTP request you're sending does not follow HTTP specification.
See [RFC7230 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3).
The problem: there are missing CRLFs.

There should be an extra CRLF after the last HTTP header, and one after the last MIME header, too.

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: The IP address of my remote server
Connection: Close
User-Agent: My client
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49

--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
Content-Type: text/plain

value
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49--
```

That will fix the "Bad Request" problem.

Although the cause of the problem is not the `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` header, you should know that it is deprecated.
Use `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` instead.
See [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41204533/7284356) and [RFC7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578).

### Example of correct request

The content type `multipart/form-data` can be used to send values and files.
The difference is only the attribute `filename`.

Modifying your HTTP request as little as possible, here is an example that sends two fields (one file and one value):

```
POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: The IP address of my remote server
Connection: Close
User-Agent: My client
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
Content-Length: 234

--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="one"; filename="example.txt"

foo
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="two"

bar
--be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49--
```

For each field, you need a `Content-Disposition` header to be able to name the field and optionally give it a filename.

`Content-Type` is optional although you may want to add one if the value comes garbled.

Modify as necessary if you only need to upload one file.

### Testing the request

Here's a neat little script that I use to test HTTP requests:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode([
    'method' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
    'uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'body' => file_get_contents('php://input'),
    'GET' => $_GET,
    'POST' => $_POST,
    'FILES' => $_FILES,
    'headers' => getallheaders(),
], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

With that script at the receiving end, I sent my example request **without modification** to my localhost server and I got this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 31 Jul 2018 11:33:57 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32)
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

254
{
    "method": "POST",
    "uri": "/index.php",
    "body": "",
    "GET": [],
    "POST": {
        "two": "bar"
    },
    "FILES": {
        "one": {
            "name": "example.txt",
            "type": "",
            "tmp_name": "C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpD6B5.tmp",
            "error": 0,
            "size": 3
        }
    },
    "headers": {
        "Host": "The IP address of my remote server",
        "Connection": "Close",
        "User-Agent": "My client",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=be0850c82dd4983ddc49a51a797dce49",
        "Content-Length": "234"
    }
}
0
```

As you can see, field "one" goes to `$_FILES` and field "two" goes to `$_POST`.

First, send the example request without modification.
Keep trying until you get the correct result.
Then modify as needed, making sure every step of the way that the request still follows HTTP specification.

Comment: As far as I get it CRLF is some kind of an empty line (`\r\n`) that goes somewhere before the actual message. In the code you posted, I see no change from what I'm doing. Also I am using `fputs($socket, join("\r\n", $httpContent)."\r\n\r\n")` to write to the fsockopen handle.

Comment: Sorry! My bad. I saw the difference: the empty row after the `Content-type: multipart/mixed` header. I added `\r\n` to this array element BEFORE joining the array using `join("\r\n", $httpContent). Thank you!

Comment: OK. Third Comment :) How to get `value`? Right after the begining of the boundary I have `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"` and then `value`. No `Content-Type`. When I try to `var_dump($_POST)` in index.php on the remote server it returns `array(0){}`. When I try to `print_r(getallheaders())` I get all headers before `--{boundary}`.

Comment: @EmilAvramov Answer updated with a working example of HTTP request.

Comment: How to get `foo` or `bar` in index.php on the server?

Comment: @EmilAvramov From `$_POST` and `$_FILES`.

Comment: Both are empty.

Comment: @EmilAvramov Make sure that the message body is exactly the same size as specified by `Content-Length`. Some servers are strict about that.

Comment: The message body contains only 
`------------------{boundary}
value
------------------{boundary}--`
and the in the headers field: `Content-Length: strlen("value")`. Still nothing.

Comment: @EmilAvramov Because you're still sending invalid request. Boundary must be followed by `Content-Disposition`, not value. `Content-Length: strlen("value")` is also incorrect, it needs the size of the message body, not the size of the value.